# python file reading line by line and check for condition and if it's not true wait until its true without skipping the line

Tags: python, file, if-statement

this is my code :

```
for line in file :
    if(something== something):
        '''do something''' .
    else:
        '''dont skip the line and wait until condition is true then skip to 
           next line'''
```

Note : im chakeing number of threads in my condition

Comment: Do you mean `while not <condition>`?

Comment: Please provide more information as in are you using multithreading to read the file line by line?

Comment: ye thanks for comment ye some thing like that but more officiant

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in file :
    while True:
        if(something== something):
            '''do something'''
            break
```

Comment: is there is no better way to do it because this code doesn't look too good

Comment: @winPack Kindly share if you find a better way.